# Regex formula spliting with preg_split

Tags: php, regex

Hello i am passing a bad moment trying to found the correct Regex formula.

```
$stringSplit = "+foo a -ba24+Sample3"; 

$vectorsPlus = preg_split('/[+*]/',$stringSplit ,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$vectorsMinus = preg_split('/[-*]/',$stringSplit ,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

My objetive it's get 2 diferents arrays grouping on symbol like:

```
$vectorsPlus [0] = '+foo';
$vectorsPlus [1] = '+Sample3';

$vectorsMinus [0] = '-ba24';
```

I will aprecciate any help how to solves this with the Regex magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can match the values.

Note that `[+*]` and `[-*]` both match a `*` char and which is not in the example data.

You can match either a `+` or a `-` followed by matching the opposite excluding whitespace chars using a negated character class.

```
$stringSplit = "+foo a -ba24+Sample3";

preg_match_all("/\+[^-+\s]+/", $stringSplit, $matchesPlus);
print_r($matchesPlus[0]);

preg_match_all("/-[^-+\s]+/", $stringSplit, $matchesMinus);
print_r($matchesMinus[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => +foo
    [1] => +Sample3
)
Array
(
    [0] => -ba24
)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/L19jg)

Comment: Thanks for your time !!, worked like a charm, but it just noticed it's will not match if the searched strings dont have a blank space beteween them, like:    stringSplit = "+foo a -ba24+Sample3";, !

Comment: @FernandoMazzoni I have updated the answer excluding matching either `-` or `+`

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird !, now it's perfect !!.